# Can force the "Title(linked to item with edit menu)" column inside my list view to reference to another URL

Tags: 2013, development, list-view, custom-form, jslink

I am working on a custom list, and inside the list view i am showing the `Title(linked to item with edit menu)` column. currently when users click on this column they will be redirected to the item display form. now our customer is asking if we can redirect to different URL when clicking on the list items?
so instead of redirecting to the item display form:-

```
/Lists/Projects/DispForm.aspx?ID=86
```

to be redirected to a sub-site that have the item ID, such as:-

```
/sites/86/
```

Thanks

**EDIT**
here is my JS link , but it did not have any effect on the views:-

```
(function () {

      function registerRenderer() {
        var ctxForm = {};
        ctxForm.Templates = {};

        ctxForm.Templates = {
            Fields : {
                'LinkTitle': { //------ Change Hyperlink from LinkTitleNoMenu field
                    View : function (ctx) {
                        var url = String.format('{0}?ID={1}', "/PMO/Projects/", ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                        return String.format('<a href="{0}" onclick="EditItem2(event, \'{0}\');return false;">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.Title);

                    }
                },
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');


})();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try to use **CSR**.

**Step 1: Create a JS file and paste below code.**

```
(function () {

      function registerRenderer() {
        var ctxForm = {};
        ctxForm.Templates = {};

        ctxForm.Templates = {
            Fields : {
                'LinkTitle': { //------ Change Hyperlink of LinkTitle
                    View : function (ctx) {
                        var url = String.format('{0}?ID={1}', "/sites/86/Lists/testlist/EditTicket.aspx", ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                        return String.format('<a href="{0}" onclick="EditItem2(event, \'{0}\');return false;">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                    }
                },
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');


})();
```

Step 2: GoTo **web part properties** of List View and add **JS Link reference** to this newly created js file **(e.g. ~sitecollection/SiteAssets/CSRTest.js)**

Step 3: Apply and Done

Please try and let me know if any query.

Comment: will try your appraoch, but i have a question as seems this js function will be applied on web-part basis not to the column itself ,, is this correct ? second question, how i can get the real name for the "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" ??

Comment: You can get real name for the field by inspect element. Here "LinkTitle" is the real name for "Title(linked to item with edit menu)".

Comment: now i follow your appraoch.. but still when i click on the title i will be redirected to the  display form.. i added my JS script

Comment: can you please check if your script is loading properly on page ?

Comment: One more thing, please try to refer js link in this format only.  "~sitecollection/YourJSfFilePath".

Comment: Ok it worked well when I define  "~sitecollection/YourJSfFilePath" .. but i have a question as i want to expand the business logic inside yours JS, mainly to only modify the title url if a column named "AutomaticallyCreated" equal True. now i define this check if(ctx.CurrentItem.AutomaticallyCreated === 'true') inside the JS before modifying the url... but this will not work unless the "AutomaticallyCreated" field is rendered inside the list view,,

Comment: but if i remove it from the list view the JS will bypass the check.. so is there a way to reference a CTX field even if the field is not being rendered inside the list view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50395/discussion-between-rohit-waghela-and-john-g).

Comment: We can only access the `ctx` fields that are rendered (available in the current list view). So what you can do is, make the column/field available in the view and hide it with CSR.  Please refer the link to hide the column with CSR --> http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168898/csr-hide-a-field-on-form-but-not-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

You can create hyperlink column and from list default view hide Title column and your newly created custom hyperlink column. It will redirect you to link which you will set.

Comment: So you prefer this appraoch over using client side rendering ? second question should i use the column template named "Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing" OR "Hyperlink or Picture" , keeping in mind that i will be attaching the itemID inside the new url such as 'servername/.../sites/ItemID'

Comment: hyperlink and picture will be fine. No need for any programming. Using OOTB you can achieve this.

Comment: now i add a test hyperlink column,, but not sure how i can define that it should render the following url "http://servername/...../sites/ITEMID" ??

Comment: now i add a test hyperlink column,, but not sure how i can define that it should render the following url "http://servername/...../sites/ITEMID" ?? is there a way to define this inside the column setting ? or i will need to populate this filed when the item is created ?

Comment: is it static link or dynamically you want to create link?

Comment: the url will have the following format "http://servername/sites/ITemID" .. so i can drive the url from the ItemID

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using [client side rendering](http://www.kaptyn.com/SharePoint/client-side-rendering-2013/) in SharePoint 2013 by redefining LinkTitle field for the view.
There is an excellent [article by Andrei Markeev](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) on this. It also has an example that satisfies your requirement.

Comment: so it is better to use CSR over defining a hyperlink column as mentioned by other replies ?

Comment: Client side rendering is meant to fulfill such requirements and would be the preferred approach

Answer (score 2):

You have to create custom hyperlink column and it will redirect to new URL.

Comment: So you prefer this appraoch over using client side rendering ? second question should i use the column template named "Hyperlink with formatting and constraints for publishing" OR "Hyperlink or Picture" , keeping in mind that i will be attaching the itemID inside the new url such as 'http://servername/.../sites/ItemID'