# How to make column description clickable

Tags: shortcut

When I have list and there are different columns, how do I make desired columns "clickable" that means when I click the field for example "Description" it will open the item for me to view

Comment: You can achieve this using CSR as well. Refer this link, this will help you -- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203041/can-force-the-titlelinked-to-item-with-edit-menu-column-inside-my-list-view/203053#203053

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it with SharePoint Designer. Navigate to the list where is the view you want to modify. Then open the view in advanced mode (Edit File in Advanced Mode). There is View element that contains ViewFields element with all fields in the view.

Just add linkToITem="TRUE" to the field and save it.

```
<View ...>
    ...
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="MyClickableColumn" ListItemMenu="TRUE" linkToItem="TRUE" />
        <FieldRef Name="Created" />
        <FieldRef Name="Author" />
    </ViewFields>
</View>
```

But you have to know that when you change the view in browser using UI, this change will be lost.