# Change hyperlink display form - content query

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, hyperlink, query, content

I am having a page called `https://example.com/sites/nl/view_item.aspx?ID=10` for example,

This displays the content in a nice visual way for that specific item. Next to that item I have made a list with the 'content query' webpart that displays the other items.

I am using the itemstyle 'title only', this displays exactly what I want, a list with the other items (title only and clickable)

But when I click on the item I want to navigate to `https://example.com/sites/nl/view_item.aspx?ID=11` (for example). Now the item is using the default URL,

what's sends me to the 'default dispform'. How can I achieve what I want?

The page view_item.aspx is already showing up in the lists of forms for that specific list but I don't want it to be default.

I hope someone can help me on this.

Comment: Refer this answer. THis will work for you - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203041/can-force-the-titlelinked-to-item-with-edit-menu-column-inside-my-list-view/203053#203053

Comment: Thanks Rohit, but I am afraid this will not work because I am using a content query webpart which is using XSL.