# How do I modify AllItems.aspx with ability to customise the fields on the page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How do I go about designing the AllItems.aspx view such that I can modify one of the columns to be a clickable URL?

When I open the field in SP Designer I get "This page does not contain any regions that are editable in safe mode". If I then open in "Advanced Mode" all I am faced with is the markup/code view.

I need to be able to edit the column so I can bind a URL field to the column.
How can this be achieved?

Comment: what version of sharepoint you using?

Comment: You can add/change hyperlink on particular field using CSR. Refer this link this will help you - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203041/can-force-the-titlelinked-to-item-with-edit-menu-column-inside-my-list-view/203053#203053

Comment: @AliJafer SP2016

Answer (score 1):

can you be a bit more specific in what you want to achieve?

why cant you create a custom view based off the default allitems view and add a new column that is type "Hyperlink or Picture". amend the view to include this new field and set this new view as default view.

or do it in sharepoint designer and amend the code accordingly.

or alternatively you would need to edit the page in browser and insert a script editor to the page and use javascript/jquery to manipulate as you please.

goto library allitems page -> click on the cog top right -> click edit page -> click "add a webpart" on the newly loaded page -> within "media and content" click on "script editor" and then click on add -> when loaded you need to click on "Edit Snippet" -> within the popup place your JS code.

Comment: I've copied the AllItems.aspx to AllItemsCustom.aspx and I can set this as the default view ok.  However, in the markup of this file there is no option to add/customise fields. I only have ContentPlaceHolders but nothing that specifies the existing columns. And there is no way to edit the page in Design mode.

Comment: design view since 2013 doesn't exist, only code view! is there any reason why you want to bind a html url to a text column unless its something like a calculated column which you cant do anymore. Point being cant you use an out of the box hyperlink column? if not and you need a specific dynamic column to be hyperlink then anywhere within a contentplaceholder like "main" you can add some javascript to loop through each item. as noted its best to have a hyperlink column instead of a text column unless its calculated based off several columns