# Jslink is not loaded at all :(

Tags: jslink

When linking to jsLink file, with console.log - is not loaded.
this is the script for example:

```
<script>
  console.log("loaded");
 </script>
```

I use it on the list view webpart as "jslink" property (I mean the address of it /SiteAssets/specialItemOrder/colorize.js)

Why isn't it loaded?

Comment: try to reference JSLInk as - `~SiteAssets/specialItemOrder/colorize.js`. Refer this - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203041/can-force-the-titlelinked-to-item-with-edit-menu-column-inside-my-list-view/203053#203053

Comment: Also there is no need to include `<script></script>` tab in your `colorize.js` file. Just write `console.log` and see ...

Comment: `~SiteAssets` is not a valid token. I'd suggest using `~sitecollection`, or `~site` here. So `~site/SiteAssets/specialItemOrder/colorize.js`

Comment: @Mike Thanks for correcting. You are right .......

Comment: Use the **Chrome Browser Exstension: Cisar**, it is a WYSIWIG editor and does all the JSLink management for you